# How to store data in a client app and download data to a main server (ionic 2/angular 2)?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, cordova, ionic2

I'm developing an app in Ionic 2/Angular 2/Cordova and I need to implement this behaviour: storing data in the client app and download data of each client to the main server database, periodically, as soon as the mobile data network on the device is available.

What is the current best practice to do this?

I would think SQLlite database on the app, mySQL database on the server and a web service for the app to call and send data. There is something pre-built to do this? (coding this from scratch seems to me like reinventing the wheel)

EDIT: after some researches I've found something called PouchDB (son of CouchDB) but I'm not sure it is sufficiently used/supported by the community to use it and hope to find help online in case of problems